# multiple view models in a single page mvvmcross

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to make an App for multiple platforms using Xamarin. The App uses the Mvvm structure and MvvmCross.

Currently, I have various View Models and they all bind great (using MvvmCross), as long as they are in separate **pages**.

However, I would like to make a single **page** that references multiple View Models. For example, a page that has few buttons each binding to methods in different View Models.

I understand that to do this I should:

1) Divide the screen to different views.

2) Assign the buttons to different views according to their View Model.

I am not sure how can I divide the screen? Are fragments the answer?

---

Also, does this mean a View Model that would know about all view models in the page is necessary?

---

My current work around is having tabs in all pages that change the current view model of that page, as follow:

```
public ICommand VM1Command
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<ViewModel1>()); }
    }
    public ICommand VM2Command
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<ViewModel2>()); }
    }
    public ICommand VM3Command
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<ViewModel3>()); }
    }
```

This is pretty ugly, I would really appreciate if anyone could refer me to somewhere where this is explained or even better tell me how to do it.

Cheers!

Comment: try http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYu_9rcAJU4 - that debunks a few view-viewmodel myths

Comment: Thank you Stuart for this comment! Your support is really superb! I edited my question to (hopefully) contain the right terminology now. I believe what I am looking for is actually how to divide the page and have multiple views in it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `SpheroViewModel` is used in the `SpheroView` (see: [SpheroView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/blob/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench.UI.Droid/Views/SpheroView.cs)). This View is a MvxBindingTabActivityView. So it uses an Android TabHost to display the Subviews as Tab. The setup is done in the lines 30 - 48. For each SubViewModel you have an own view (e.g. [SpheroAccelMovementView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/blob/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench.UI.Droid/Views/SpheroSubViews/SpheroAccelMovementView.cs)) that binds and displays the separate data.

For more Details on Tabs and MvvMCross and different Platforms have a look at [N = 25 - Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbdPDZmuHk8). There are **perhaps** some API changes since stuart has recored the video. But it explains the general idea of tabs and subviewmodels.

Comment: Thank you @Sven-Michael Stube for the answer. I am sorry that I wasn't very clear in my question before. If I understand correctly in that example every view model is in a different tab, where I actually wanted few view model in a single tab.